Extract file while downloading it with aria2c
I'm trying to download and extracting a snapshot at the same time.
aria2c -o geth.tar.lz4 -s14 -x14 -k100M https://pub-c0627345c16f47ab858c9469133073a8.r2.dev/geth-pbss-pebble-20240705.tar.lz4 | lz4 -d - | tar -xv
but it is raising the error
Error 44 : Unrecognized header : file cannot be decoded
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

with wget instead it works fine
 wget -O - "https://pub-c0627345c16f47ab858c9469133073a8.r2.dev/geth-pbss-pebble-20240705.tar.lz4" | lz4 -d - | tar -xv
but it takes much long. is there a way to extract the file while downloading it white aria2c ?

With -o geth.tar.lz4 the tool writes to geth.tar.lz4, not to its stdout. Even if the tool can write to its stdout in some cases, I don't expect this to work with -s14. Do you know what -s14 does when you download a single file? How do you expect this and piping to stdout to work at the same time? This would require delaying writes and storing chunks in a temporary file (or in memory, whatever). Probably not implemented, because downloading to a regular file you can use later is almost as good. So do just that.

-s, --split= Download a file using N connections. […] N connections total are made simultaneously. The number of connections to the same host is restricted by the --max-connection-per-server option. See also the --min-split-size option. Default: 5
